# How can i convert a string into byte[] of unsigned int 32 C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string like `"0x5D, 0x50, 0x68, 0xBE, 0xC9, 0xB3, 0x84, 0xFF"`.
I want to convert it into:

```
byte[] key= new byte[] { 0x5D, 0x50, 0x68, 0xBE, 0xC9, 0xB3, 0x84, 0xFF};
```

I thought about splitting the string by `,` then loop on it and setvalue into another `byte[]` in index of `i`

```
string Key = "0x5D, 0x50, 0x68, 0xBE, 0xC9, 0xB3, 0x84, 0xFF";

    string[] arr = Key.Split(',');
    byte[] keybyte= new byte[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
         keybyte.SetValue(Int32.Parse(arr[i].ToString()), i);
    }
```

but seems like it doesn't work. I get error in converting the string into unsigned int32 on the first beginning.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
byte[] data =
  Key
  .Split(new string[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Select(s => Byte.Parse(s.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
keybyte[i] = byte.Parse(arr[i].Trim().Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: still getting the type error "Input string was not in a correct format." while it is arr[i] "0x5D" string in the watch :S

Comment: well thanx i used ur solution with lc solution and it worked. urs missed the subscripting part

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly specify `AllowHexSpecifier` (or `HexNumber` - see the documentation below for details). Also, hex strings to be passed to `Parse` cannot have the 0x prefix, so you'll have to strip them out first.

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx):

> Indicates that the numeric string represents a hexadecimal value. Valid hexadecimal values include the numeric digits 0-9 and the hexadecimal digits A-F and a-f. Hexadecimal values can be left-padded with zeros. Strings parsed using this style are not permitted to be prefixed with "0x".

So try:

```
Int32.Parse(arr[i].Substring(2), 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
```

Also, you mentioned using an unsigned integer. Did you mean to use `UInt32` instead?

Additionally, not sure why you were calling an additional `ToString` on a `string`...